# Using Conversion Factors to Determine Exchange Rate

Tags: abstract-algebra

While in Europe, if you drive 125km per day, how much money would you spend on gas in one week if gas costs 1.10 euros per liter and your car's gas mileage is 39.0mi/gal ? Assume that 1 euro = 1.26 dollars.

Express your answer numerically in dollars.

My answer is $46 dollars. Am I correct?

I multiplied 125 by 7 to get 875km (7days)

I then converted kilogram to miles (0.6214 mi) / (1km) X 1gal / (39.0 mi) x 3.78 l/ gal = 52.6995L

52.6995 L X 1.10 euros = 57.96945

€57.96945 / $1.26 = 46.0075

Also which number determines my final calculations in significant figures?

Comment: Kilograms to miles! Quite some conversion. :)

Comment: Right at the end. You have taken \$1=1.26 euros. It should be the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is fine until the end. Since 1 euro = \$1.26, you should be multiplying instead of dividing, giving \$73.0415 (I have just been calculating in Mathematica).

That leaves the question of how to round that to give the correct number of significant figures.

The crude answer is to notice that all the data in the question is given to 3 significant figures (I suspect you pulled down the more accurate km/miles figure yourself). So we are probably expected to give the answer to 3 significant figures, ie $73.0.

As a practical matter if the question did not say anything specific about significant figures you would probably either give it to the nearest dollar, or to the nearest cent.

If you want a more accurate answer you are into some complicated calculation. So I would say \$73 if the question said nothing about significant figures, or \$73.0 if it did.